# Outlook Blank Subject Crashes Rules... VBA to Resolve doesn't show in Scripts list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

So there is a known bug in Outlook, where my blank subject lines in incoming rules on IMAP&SMTP accounts cause forwarding rules to error and crash, and ultimately disables the rule.

I thought a way around this would be to write a VBA to append a string to the subject line, this way blank subject lines will atleast contain the appended string.

```
Sub myRuleMacro()
Dim xItem As Object
Dim xNewSubject As String
Dim xMailItem As MailItem
Dim xExplorer As Explorer
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Set xExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
For i = xExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set xItem = xExplorer.Selection.item(i)
    If xItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set xMailItem = xItem
        With xMailItem
            xNewSubject = "RE: " & .Subject
            .Subject = xNewSubject
            .Save
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This works like a charm when manually run, however it doesn't show up in the Scripts list within rules.

[image: Blank Scripts List]

Looking at other posts it says the first line should be

```
Sub myRuleMacro(item as Outlook.MailItem)
```

with the addition of the bit in the brackets there. However, whilst this then appears in the list of scripts in my Outlook Rules, trying to run the VBA manually or step through gives me this as if the macro does not exist

[image: Photo of Error when running using F5]

Any thoughts on what / where I am going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a VBA procedure to show up as a Macro it needs:

1. To be `Public` (Which is the default so you're good here)
2. To have no mandatory parameters (This is where you went wrong)

You don't need it to be visible as a macro for it to work. If you want to test it you need a helper sub like this:

```
Public Sub testMyRuleMacro()
    Dim CurrentMessage As MailItem
    Dim SelectedItems As Selection
    Set SelectedItems = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each CurrentMessage In SelectedItems
        myRuleMacro CurrentMessage
    Next CurrentMessage
End Sub
```

Finally, it looks like you are trying to run a rule to fix your rules. That sounds like a recipe for disaster. I would instead suggest that you use VBA events to run your code to fix the rules so the rules can run.

To do that you need to place your event procedure in to `ThisOutlookSession` which is a built-in Module that exists for the Outlook application itself. This is where Outlook stores all of it's event procedures.

Yours would look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
    
' Set up the listener on the Inbox
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
      
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

' This runs for each item added to the inbox
Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Dim EMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set EMail = Item
   
        Debug.Print "Incoming Data."
        myRuleMacro EMail

        Set EMail = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

The `InboxItems_ItemAdd` is an event that fires every time an object lands in the Inbox. Not all Outlook objects are mail so we test for that to exclude things that would cause an error in our code that expects mail.

Comment: ThisOutlookSession did not provide an output, I would have expected an output message of Incoming Data. I think because there is still a Rule to move this message.

My outlook rules which I think makes logical sense is 1) Run Script to Identify Blank Subject Lines & Repair. Then Rule 2, forward the email and move to a folder called "Forwarded".

Comment: `InboxItems_ItemAdd` will run for EVERY item regardless of whatever else you are doing. I apologize that I left out a critical part of this solution. It's been a while since I looked at this code. See my edit. You will have to then close Outlook so that the `Application_Startup` event can run to set up your listener.

Comment: @HenryAspden, did this work? Did you get it to run?